# Web Lead Forms in SugarCRM

Tags: email, crm, notifications, sugarcrm, lead

Since the generated web lead forms in SugarCRM have the assigned_user_id same as the creator_user_id, the system doesn't send any mail notification.

How to force SugarCRM to send a mail notification every time a lead is submitted without checking creator_user_id and assigned_user_id?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been forever, but maybe this will help somebody else.

https://panther.sugarcrm.com/forums/showpost.php?p=222980&postcount=10

I searched for "$current_user->retrieve($_REQUEST['assigned_user_id']);" and that found it.

The next step after this is usually adding email and phone to the notification email:

http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/showpost.php?p=207882&postcount=3

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I have a web lead form setup that only has the hidden input field 'assigned_user_id', and that person receives an email each time a lead is submitted.

you also need to make sure your SMTP settings are properly configured (at least for the root/admin user, I think) so the system can actually send out emails.

what version of sugarcrm are you using?